# How to modify Linux ISO (like Ubuntu) and add my custom bash to it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I googled and I see something like Cubic but I don't think it fits my problem.

What I want to do is (suppose the talking .iso file is an Ubuntu):

```
During the installation, it does this:
> echo I'm now installed, ip is $(ip route get 1.1.1.1) > /root/installed_$(HOSTNAME)
> curl ... (with curl for example, I want to upload this file to another server which is the master server, so that I can tell master server it is now installed)
```

This is a very simple file that I want to see if I can append such thing to a `.iso` file and whenever I installed using this iso, my master server is updated and knows new server is now added (I do something in the master server when the file in master is updated).

Is that possible add a custom file to .iso file with bash shell?

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the ISO whichever way you like, even to adding to `crontab`
an entry to run a script after boot which will do this one-time action.

From the article
[How to create custom linux ISO image?](https://www.linuxscrew.com/how-to-create-custom-linux-iso-image)

Mount the ISO image :

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/image
sudo mount /path/to/your.iso /mnt/image -o loop
```

Copy contents :

```
mkdir /tmp/newiso
cp -r /mnt/image /tmp/newiso
```

Modify the files in `/tmp/newiso` whichever way you like.

Create the new ISO image in `/tmp` :

```
cd /tmp/newiso
sudo mkisofs -o /tmp/new.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -V "new iso name"
```

For running a task after boot, use a `crontab` entry such as :

```
@reboot [path to shell script]
```

See this article for more information :
[Crontab on Boot: Run a Cron Job at Boot Time](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/crontab-reboot)

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to add crontab in the OS. I just want to run something "only during installation". For example I want to add a custom repo and install a package from there only one time and do something else with a bash file, and when it's installing.

Comment: Instead of modifying `crontab`, see the section "Running a Final Script" in the article [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization).

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for Ubuntu 20 and later: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/server-installer-plans-for-20-04-lts/13631 and I should look at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference.